# how to populate two different select boxes with onchange jquery post

Tags: jquery, post, onchange

researched on that but i couldn't find my solution. i have select box of books like.

```
<select name="book" id="book">
<option value="1">fasion</option>
<option value="2">games</option>
<option value="3">sports</option>
</select>
```

i'm sending book id with jquery post and fetching records and populating it's categories in another select box in id of #slcCatList from database.

```
$('#book').change(getDropdownLoads);
function getDropdownLoads() {
    var bid = $(this).val();
    $.post('fetchdata.php', { master_book_id : bid }, populateDropdown, 'html');
}

function populateDropdown(data) {
    if (data != 'error') {
        $('#slcCatList').html(data);
    }
}
```

fetchdata.php returning results against this query for select box #slcCatList 
works fine.

```
select * from books where id = $bid" // which also has author_name

<select id="slcCatList "> 
</select>
```

what i need is, that similarly i want to populate another select box #authorName against this same query using same post request.

```
<select id="authorName ">
// fetched author_name
</select>
```

How i can do that ?

Comment: Call `$.post()` after both options selected , with value from each selection ?

Comment: did you try JSON for that..

Comment: @ guest271314, second select authorName is not populated or loaded on page load. it needs author_name when jquery data returns. that's the target. ____ @rohit, could you please give an idea to do with JSON ? but i believe it should done in same scenario.

Comment: @user2349450 _"second select authorName is not populated or loaded on page load."_ Yes. Tried calling `$.post()` after both `select` elements have value ?

Comment: @guest271314 after $.post() second select <options> load fine as of `$('#slcCatList').html(data);` third `<select id="authorName ">` is there with no <options> there i need `author_name` from same data callback.

Comment: _"is there with no <options> there i need author_name from same data callback."_ No `option` elements at `#authorName`  `select`  ? Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? Is expected result to use `$.post()`  to send values of both `#book` , `#authorName` after `#authorName` loaded into `DOM` ?

Comment: before answering , i need to be satisfied ,that i understood the problem .So you need to populate two dropdown on change event of first dropdown . umm?

Comment: @RohitKumar yeah right. 1st select will load subCat and 2nd author_name.

Comment: @user2349450 _"1st select will load subCat and 2nd author_name"_ Tried event delegation `$(document).on("change", "select", getDropdownLoads)` ? , chaining `.then(populateDropdown)` to `$.post()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using mysql at backend.I am providing some codes , having some assumed variable -

By using json you can write response to seprate both select tags.

**PHP**

```
//---
$dropDown1='<select id="slcCatList ">';
$dropDown2='<select id="authorName">';

$q="select * from books where id = $bid" ;
$rs=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs,MYSQL_BOTH)
{
 $dropDown1 .='<option>'.$row['category'].'</option>';
 $dropDown2 .='<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
$dropDown1 .='</select >';
$dropDown2 .='</select >';

$result=array("category"=>$dropDown1,"name"=>$dropDown2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

At client side , i am denoting the required function definition you may need . You have to create two div which will wrap your both dropdowns say (slcCatListWrapper,authorNameWrapper)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function populateDropdown(data) {
    if (data != 'error') {
        var obj=JSON.parse(data);
        $('#slcCatListWrapper').html(obj.category);
        $('#authorNameWrapper').html(obj.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JSON` worked well to add values specifically without creating `<select>` elements. thank you very much.